# APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token for Sender ID 'xxxxxxxxxx'. Notifications to this FCM Token will not be delivered over APNS

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, flutter-notification

APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token for Sender ID 'xxxxxxxxxx'. Notifications to this FCM Token will not be delivered over APNS. Be sure to re-retrieve the FCM token once the APNS device token is set.

I have added the key and auth file for APNS in firebase but still getting errors. Anyone expert who solved this issue please reply to me . as the error attached in the image[image_err](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e66L1.jpg)

Comment: Have you enabled push notification in capabilities?

Comment: Be careful as notifications are not supported on iOS simulator.

Comment: yes i have enabled in capabilities.

Comment: i uploaded it on testflight and then tested still not working on real devices